# How to move visual studio projects (xamarin.forms) from windows to macOS computer?

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm planning to transfer my xamarin.forms projects from my windows computer to my macOS computer.
Will copying the files from C:/Users/Username/source/repos/[All Projects/Files] provides me enough data to run/code my projects in the new macOS computer or do I need to copy additional file beside this path?

This is my first time using mac operating system.

Comment: You really ought to be using version control -- something like GitHub or GitLab. That way you don't even have to worry about this. As long as you have a suitbale .gitignore for Visual Studio alongside your code you can rest assured that you will be pushing only the necessary files up to the remote then just use `git clone` to pull all the files to your Mac. Double-click the SLN file on your Mac to open it up in Visual Studio for Mac and you can build like normal.

Comment: @carrot Hi ..Does it worked for you ? Even though you copy the code check all the references and mostly you need to check the nuget packages config ...which would be different for windows and mac visual studio..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are some 'ifs' for which this wouldn't work (most notably your project can reference any file on the disk and as such it won't work on any other device until you 'fix' those external files) for most projects it is enough to copy just the data that you have quoted.

Answer (score 1):

You're need to install all required environment including Xamarin for iOS, Xamarin for Android. If you are planning to continue using Visual Studio on Mac it won't be a problem for you to setup environment. Just try to open your solution in Visual Studio for Mac and it prepares everything for you.